# Is this (Wii) Guitar Hero controller normal?

Tags: nintendo-wii, guitar-hero

I bought this Wii GH controller on ebay and I can't handle to put it together.

My guess is that the neck is from another controller because the connection ports are totally different.

Please tell me if the neck is from a controller for another console or if I'm just too dumb to put this together?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9hEF.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behold the Guitar Hero World Tour guitar for the Wii: [image]

AKAIK all first party guitars had colors on the solo section of the neck, not colored dots on the side. Spending the past 30 minutes, I can't even find a guitar neck that matches that style, so I can't say exactly *what* it's for.

But really, it all boils down to simply ensuring that it doesn't fit. Orient the neck properly and try to slide it down. If it doesn't fit then it doesn't fit, and it's time to contact the seller.

Comment: The body is a World Tour guitar, while the neck belongs to a Guitar Hero 5/Band Hero guitar.

Answer (score 0):

If the connection ports are different, then you definitely have a mismatched neck and body as far as Guitar Hero controller parts are concerned. It is absolutely not your fault in this case - with this as well as any "plug-in" of this sort along with any computer ports, the ports have to match for it to fit, and if they don't, it is absolutely not your fault for not fitting them - you are absolutely right about the ports not fitting! This might not have been intentional on the seller's part, but it is definitely time to contact the seller about this.